# Django Multiple Forms Handling

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am new to Django and tried making a view that holds a list of forms and handles them. I am familiar with the FormView provided by django's generic views however it only holds one form in it. 
The idea is that the main form I have is split into a few forms, and then the "mini-forms" are held in a list ("forms"). 
Since I'm splitting the form into parts and saving a list of forms (for reasons like re-usability and such), the template looks something like this (which does the trick):

```
...
<form ...>
  {% for form in forms %}
   {{ form.as_p }}
  {% endfor %}
  <input type="submit"...>
</form>
...
```

I have been messing around with the view that should handle the forms, validate them and will get the data from them. Since I feel like Im making it more complicated than it should really be, I'd like to ask you to give an example of a simple view for that, that Ill develop further (get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be more a comment but I don't have quite enough rep to respond as a comment so I'm putting this in an answer:

If your primary concern is reusability have you considered creating Mixins instead of making a list of forms?
an example of this could be:

```
from django import forms

class NameFormMixin(object):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name')

class EmailFormMixin(object):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Your Email')

class NameEmailForm(forms.Form,
                    NameFormMixin,
                    EmailFormMixin):
    pass
```

you could  include your validation functions in the mixins and have general django form functions in the main form class.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I was using mixins in a similar way, but when I think about it the approach you suggested can definitely make it easier at a very small cost of generic code (since my original plan was to use a ModelForm for each part which is a bit more flexible in my eyes).